# SBJson Parsing without a key

Tags: objective-c, ios, sbjson

I have this json string by getting a response from using singleton client(RestKit).

```
[
   {
      "created_at":"Tue Apr 24 19:25:14 +0000 2012",
      "id":132456,
   },
   {
      "created_at":"Tue Apr 24 19:25:14 +0000 2012",
      "id":13456,
   },
]
```

I got this result by

```
NSDictionary *results = [[response bodyAsString] JSONValue];
```

which results to this

```
(
   {
      "created_at" = "Tue Apr 24 19:25:14 +0000 2012";
      "id"=132456;
   }
   {
      "created_at" = "Tue Apr 24 19:25:14 +0000 2012";
      "id"=132456;
   }
)
```

as NSDictionary.

As you can see there is no key available for me to get. If so, I would have done a code like this `NSMutableArray *block = [results objectForKey:@"key"];`. I tried to put and empty string for objectForKey but it doesn't work and gave me an error "objectForKey".

Question:
How can I parse every block to put it inside an array without a key?

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually is an Array of 2 Dictionaries.  Change your code:

```
NSDictionary *results = [[response bodyAsString] JSONValue];
```

to

```
NSArray *results = [[response bodyAsString] JSONValue];
```

Then you can use a For-In to get all the Dictionaries from that array if you need to.  The Key appears to be the id attribute.

So for the first one in the array:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)[results objectAtIndex:0];
NSInteger myKey = [[dictionary valueForKey@"id"] intValue];
```